# How to create a variable with SUBSET FUNCTION in R

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to create a new variable in a dataframe base on conditions from other variables:

```
SUBSET01$poverty_t <- 0
#Never poor
SUBSET01$poverty_t[SUBSET01$yr_interview=="2018" & SUBSET01$yr_interview=="2019" & SUBSET01$Poverty=="0"] <- 0
#Poor in both periods
SUBSET01$poverty_t[SUBSET01$yr_interview=="2018" & SUBSET01$yr_interview=="2019" & SUBSET01$Poverty=="1"] <- 2
#Poor in period 1
SUBSET01$poverty_t[SUBSET01$yr_interview=="2018"& SUBSET01$Poverty=="1"] <- -1
#Poor in period 2
SUBSET01$poverty_t[SUBSET01$yr_interview=="2019" & SUBSET01$Poverty=="1"] <- 1

SUBSET01$poverty_t<-factor(SUBSET01$poverty_t)
summary(SUBSET01$poverty_t)
  -1    0    1 
7254 1014 6047
```

the first two are not working(poverty_t=0, poverty=2). Is it because the subset function doesn´t work with 3 conditions?

Comment: I think you need `SUBSET01$poverty_t[SUBSET01$yr_interview=="2018" | SUBSET01$yr_interview=="2019" | SUBSET01$Poverty=="0"] <- 0`. Note that I changed `&` (and) to `|` (or).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that you have a data.frame with a variable called `yr_interview` and that each row of that column has one value, e.g.

```
id  Poverty  yr_interview
1   1        2018
1   0        2019
2   0        2018
    ...      ...
k   0        2019
```

The code you have written doesn't work because `yr_interview` can never be both 2019 and 2018. One solution would be to reshape your data such that there is a variable for poverty status in 2018 and a variable for poverty status in 2019, e.g.

```
id    pov_18    pov_19
1     1         0
2     0         0 
3     1         1
...   ...       ... 
k     1         0
```